# Please help me to solve this useEffect issue

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage

The app works fine and adds the added data to the localhost but when I reload I lose the data, But it should be there from Localhost. It looks like I am using the useEffect the wrong way. Please check the code and help me to know what I am doing wrong here. Thanks

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function PetApp() {
  const [pets, setPets] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (localStorage.getItem('examplePetData')) {
      setPets(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('examplePetData')));
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('examplePetData', JSON.stringify(pets));
  }, [pets]);

  return (
    <>
      <AddPetForm setPets={setPets} />
      <ul>
        {pets.map(pet => (
          <Pet setPets={setPets} id={pet.id} name={pet.name} species={pet.species} age={pet.age} key={pet.id} />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
}

function AddPetForm(props) {
  const [name, setName] = useState();
  const [species, setSpecies] = useState();
  const [age, setAge] = useState();

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    props.setPets(prev => prev.concat({ name, species, age, id: Date.now() }));
    setName('');
    setSpecies('');
    setAge('');
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Add New Pet</legend>
        <input value={name} onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)} placeholder="Name" />
        <input value={species} onChange={e => setSpecies(e.target.value)} placeholder="species" />
        <input value={age} onChange={e => setAge(e.target.value)} placeholder="age in years" />
        <button>Add Pet</button>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  );
}

function Pet(props) {
  function handleDelete() {
    props.setPets(prev => prev.filter(pet => pet.id != props.id));
  }

  return (
    <li>
      {props.name} is a {props.species} and is {props.age} years old.
      <button onClick={handleDelete}>Delete</button>
    </li>
  );
}
export default PetApp;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are in React.Strict mode where the effects are called twice and ideally if your methods are pure this should give the same response.
React strict mode helps find impurities like this only. You could validate this by removing the strict mode and your code would work.

However this should be fixed instead of removing strict mode

https://react.dev/reference/react/useMemo#my-calculation-runs-twice-on-every-re-render

You could fix this by setting the initial state like

```
  const [pets, setPets] = useState(()=>{
    if (localStorage.getItem('examplePetData')) {
      return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('examplePetData'));
    }
    return [];
  });
```

and removing the

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (localStorage.getItem('examplePetData')) {
      setPets(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('examplePetData')));
    }
  }, []);
```